# Yii2 validation - allow commas and dots in the number

Tags: yii, yii2

I have number which can be strict number or can take this kind of format **12,314.00** (comma will separate long number and dot is used for decimal.

How can I prevent the **must be a number** error when the number is formatted this way?

Comment: Does the actual data consumer (database, etc.) allow commas?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the "numberPattern" of your validator: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-numbervalidator.html#$numberPattern-detail

Answer (score 0):

Well we have an option of [**`Masked`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-maskedinput.html) Input so that you can force the user to enter the number on the frontend in the desired format and save it in the normal form.
The masked text field is implemented based on the 
[**`jQuery input masked plugin`**](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

[image]

You can use them like

```
echo MaskedInput::widget([
    'name' => 'price',
    'mask' => '99,999.99$',
]);
```

or with ActiveForm like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'price')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
    'mask' => '99,999.99$',
]) ?>
```

This way you can still keep the number in normal form in the database i.e  `12532.05` and display it in the above format any time using Masked Input.

Comment: can we do inside `<?php $gridColumns =[ ........]?>`

Comment: @Moeez yes you can